# In MarioKart Wii, I beat the Normal Staff Ghost in Yoshi's Fall, but the Expert Ghost didn't come out?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

I learned that 4 Normal Staff Ghosts need to be beaten, and then the Funky Kong will be unlocked.

So I just beat Normal Staff Ghost  Nin*DoTak 01:16.461 for Yoshi's Fall, but I don't see any Expert Staff Ghost?  (Nin*DoTak as mentioned in http://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Kart_Wii  so the Expert Staff Ghost should be Nin*FJ )

Isn't the Expert Staff Ghost suppose to come out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to beat the normal staff ghost by [a sufficient margin](http://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Kart_Wii#Expert_Staff_Ghosts) in order to see the staff ghost.  You just need to work on improving your time a bit more in order to see him.